# Roots of a sequence of function in certain disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a sequence of functions defined by $$ g_n(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{z^{-k}}{k!}$$
Given $r>0$ show that we can find $M(r)$ such that if $n>M(r)$, then all the zeros of $g_n(z)$ lie within $D(0,r)$

If I expand the series for a finite term and set $g_n(z)=0$ , we can see the roots of $g_n(z)$ lie within a disk of certain radius because of the negative exponent.But this is not a better way of doing, I guess. I do not know how to start formally.

I was thinking about this too:
 $\lim_{ n\to \infty}  g_n(z)=e^{1/z}-1$

But did not see any link to the problem:

Any suggestion:

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $g_n(z) = e^{1/z} - 1 - R_n(z)$.  Estimate $|R_n(z)|$.
Note that if $|z|$ is large, $z (e^{1/z} - 1)$ is near $1$.

Comment: I could not see how this is associated with the zeros in a certain disk.

Comment: If $|z|$ is too large, $g_n(z)/z$ is too close to $1$ to  be $0$.

Comment: $|R_n(z)|\leq \frac{M }{(n+1)!|z|^{n+1}}$ where $|f^{n+1}(0)|\leq M$  but $f^{n+1}(0)$ is not defined. So how do I estimate $|R_n(z)|$?

Comment: Explicitly estimate the terms in the sum $\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty (1/z)^j/j!$; note that $j! \ge n! (n+1)^(j-n)$.